# Swift: Change value of another ViewController with delegation programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to change the value of one ViewController by clicking a button inside a second ViewController with delegation. 
But so far it only prints a message, but doesn't change the value.

I have this class where I defined a view:

```
class CounterView: UIView {

    public var creditPointValue = Int()

    let label = UILabel()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .cyan

        self.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "Credit Points: \(creditPointValue)"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    func changeCreditPointValue(value:Int){
        creditPointValue = creditPointValue + value
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I am using that view inside this ViewController and I want to manipulate the variable "creditPointValue":

```
protocol AddCreditsDelegate {
    func addCreditsToCounter()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: AddCreditsDelegate?

    var counterView = CounterView()

    let label = UILabel()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(button)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("View2", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeView), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.addSubview(counterView)
        counterView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        counterView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        counterView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        //counterView.frame.size.height = 30
        counterView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: counterView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true


    }

    @objc func changeView(){
        delegate?.addCreditsToCounter()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

And inside this second ViewController I am trying to change the value by clicking the button I added to the view:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(button)
               button.backgroundColor = .red
               button.setTitle("add Credits", for: .normal)
               button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCreditsButton), for: .touchUpInside)
               button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
               button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func addCreditsButton(){
        addCreditsToCounter()
    }    
}

extension ViewController2 : AddCreditsDelegate{
    func addCreditsToCounter() {
        let vc = ViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.counterView.creditPointValue += 5
        print("pressed")
    }
}
```

So far only the message "pressed" gets printed each time I click the button and I don't even know if I am going into the right direction with my approach trying to use delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new `ViewController` instance each time you call `ViewController2.addCreditsToCounter`, you already have a `ViewController` that creates a `ViewController2` instance in `ViewController.changeView`. Just store a weak reference to `ViewController` in `ViewController2` using delegate. In such case `ViewController` (not `ViewController2`) should conform to `AddCreditsDelegate`.
First of all, replace

```
protocol AddCreditsDelegate {
    func addCreditsToCounter()
}
```

with

```
protocol AddCreditsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func addCreditsToCounter()
}
```

Then add `weak var delegate: AddCreditsDelegate?` to `ViewController2` and remove `ViewController.delegate`. Remove `ViewController2.addCreditsToCounter`, `ViewController2` should not conform to `AddCreditsDelegate`. It means that in `ViewController2.addCreditsButton` you should call `delegate?.addCreditsToCounter()`, not `addCreditsToCounter()`.

`ViewController` should conform to `AddCreditsDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: AddCreditsDelegate {
    func addCreditsToCounter() {
        counterView.creditPointValue += 5
        print("pressed")
    }
}
```

And don't forget to initialize `ViewController2.delegate`. Replace your `ViewController.changeView` implementation with

```
let controller = ViewController2()
controller.delegate = self
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. 
But now I have another problem. 
While the counterView.creditPointValue adds each time the value 5 to its value, which I can see by printing the value in the output console.
The Label of counterView() won't adjust to the changes and remains at 0.

Comment: Ok I got now myself. Had to add this line off code to the function addCreditToCounter:
counterView.label.text = "Credit Points: \(counterView.creditPointValue)"

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance here

```
  let vc = ViewController()
```

instead you need

```
@objc func changeView() {  
 let sec = ViewController2(),
 sec.delegate = self
 navigationController?.pushViewController( animated: true)
}
```

Then declare this inside the SecondVC

```
weak var delegate:ViewController?
```

Finally

```
    func addCreditsToCounter() {  
        delegate?.counterView.creditPointValue += 5
        print("pressed")
    }
```